# How to retrieve efficiently using Coubase Python Client Library?

Tags: python, performance-testing, couchbase

**Action:** I run the following code:

```
#Code to fetch a key from Couachbase serially again and again
from couchbase.client import Couchbase
couchbase = Couchbase("ubuntumartini03", "default", "")
bucket = couchbase["martini-tag-manager"]
while True:
    print bucket.get("somekey")
```

**Result:** Running this code I was able to make ***500 ops per sec***.

**Action:** I ran four instances of this code.

**Result:** I was able to make ***2000 ops per sec***.

**Conclusion:** Bottleneck is something else than max possible ops couchbase can entertain per sec OR max possible ops the given machine can make, for the above given code.

## **Question:**

> ```
> How to make max possible ops per sec by single instance itself?
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Couchbase Pytnon client is basically synchronous and doesn't leverage multiple cores that you probably have. It's trying to implement multi-threaded behavior but with CPython interpreter it's absolutely pointless. Only complete re-implementation using something like Gevent would help.

Also take a look at this [bug](http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/PYCBC-28).

Comment: I am using Tornado to make request. How can I enhance my performance?